# Wordpress plugin blog creation

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, oop

I'm trying to create a custom plugin for my website.

```
class SoaneNews
{
    function __construct(){
        add_action( 'init', array($this,'pluginprefix_setup_post_type'));   
    }   

    function activate(){
        pluginprefix_setup_post_type();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    function deactivate(){ }

    function pluginprefix_setup_post_type() {
      register_post_type( 'book', ['public' => 'true',] );
    }
}

if(class_exists('SoaneNews')){
    $soanenews = new SoaneNews();
}
```

it will show this fatal error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pluginprefix_setup_post_type()

please help me to resolve these issues. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pluginprefix_setup_post_type()` is a method inside the `SoaneNews` class, not a function, but inside your `activate()` method you've called a function with that name:

```
function activate(){
    pluginprefix_setup_post_type();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

To call the `pluginprefix_setup_post_type()` method from within the class, you need to do it like this:

```
$this->pluginprefix_setup_post_type();
```

Comment: thanks, man. it's working fine now.